# Pygame Font.render() cropping uppercase letters with acute accents, tilde or circunflex

Tags: python, fonts, rendering, pygame, diacritics

I am trying to recreate my tiny python/pygame project to include multiple languages, and one of the problems I have encountered is the fact that for some reason the accents, tildes etc. are being cropped from the top so only 1 or 2 pixels of them are visible. This applies to most of the 'accented' uppercase letters in ie. French, Polish, Spanish, German, etc.
This happens both in python 2.7.2 and python 3.2, using default pygame font.

Trying to render the following string:
'ÀÂÉÈÊËÎÏÔÙÛÜŸ'

results in the rendered image like this:
[image: French letters]

I guess, I am using the standard rendering/blitting technique:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #...
    value = 'ÀÂÉÈÊËÎÏÔÙÛÜŸ'
    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
        try:
            val = unicode(value, "utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            val = value
        text = font.render("%s" % (val), 1, font_color)
    else:
        val = value
        text = font.render("%s" % (val), 1, font_color)
    self.image.blit(text, (300,300))
    #...
```

anyone have had this problem before? any workarounds? or is it just that pygame.font.render creates too small surface to accommodate the extra space needed at the top? Maybe some way to set the line height, but I haven't found that anywhere...

Comment: Try specifying a font rather than the one youa re using (are you using the default one?) - it is most likely a problem in the font.

Comment: Also, on a happy side note: one of the changes in the upcoming Python 3.3 is to add back the `u` string prefix (it will be a no-op in Python 3) - so the workaround you have to make in this case won't be needed anymore for code to run both in Python 2.7 and 3.3

Comment: thanks, will try to specify a font. I have to keep it Python 2.7 compatible because it's still default version in my OS.

Comment: I promoted my comment to an answer after testing it here. As for Python 2.7 it is nice to have it - indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying a font rather than the one youa re using (are you using the default one?) - it is most likely a problem in the font. - It worked for me with all fonts I tried in my system.

For full games, an ideal solution is distributing the font file alongside your project - since Pygame open fonts given the ".ttf" file name.

For using a system font, you have to chain calls  pygame.font.get_fonts()- to get font names, to `pygame.font.match_font` to actually get the path to the font file given the font name, and finally pygame.font.Font passing that path and a point-size to get a usable font object (with the `render` method)

```
>>> pygame.font.get_fonts()
[u'lohitbengali', u'liberationserif', u'dejavuserif', u'wenquanyimicroheimono', u'dejavulgcsans', u'arplumingcn', u'msam10', u'jomolhari', u'esint10', u'cmr10', u'arplumingtwmbe', u'dejavusans', u'lohitgujarati', u'lohitpunjabi', u'arplumingtw', u'arpluminghk', u'dejavusansmono', u'lohitassamese', u'lohitkannada', u'wenquanyimicrohei', u'khmeros', u'waree', u'lohittamil', u'wasy10', u'padauk', u'lohitdevanagari', u'paktypenaqsh', u'abyssinicasil', u'meera', u'eufm10', u'cmex10', u'khmerossystem', u'lklug', u'lohitoriya', u'msbm10', u'liberationsans', u'rsfs10', u'opensymbol', u'cmsy10', u'lohittelugu', u'paktypetehreer', u'cmmi10', u'liberationmono', u'khmeroscontent']

>>> f2 = pygame.font.match_font(u'paktypetehreer')
>>> f2
u'/usr/share/fonts/paktype-tehreer/PakType_Tehreer.ttf'
>>> font = pygame.font.Font(f2, 60)
>>> f = font.render(u"maçã, joão", 1, (255,255,255))
>>> scr.blit(f, (200,100))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, looks like you are right. The default pygame font does not deal with those letters very well. Using the pygame.font.Font(None, font_size) did not pay off. I'll actually try to distribute font with the project rather than counting on someone having the font I need.